# Spring Session jdbc don't save session from web services

Tags: spring, spring-session

i have a single page application (Angular) that calls web services deployed on spring boot.
I do authenticate trought spring security backed up with jdbc.
When i call service /user (secured) with a web service providing Authorization header, spring do the login correctly but don't save the session on db.
If i call the same service directly from browser I get the browser login popup for basic authentication, than spring do the login correctly and save the session on db.
What could cause in the first case that the session is not stored?

request headers for case 1:

```
GET /user HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Basic c3RlZXZlOnB3ZA==
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=9db7df58-99fc-45a6-a04a-9a686c72e3f8; SESSION=NzA5MzQ4MTMtNjlmOS00OWJkLTlhNmYtNDhiYzliOGIyNTgy
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

request headers for case 2:

```
GET /user HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Basic c3RlZXZlOnB3ZA==
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=9db7df58-99fc-45a6-a04a-9a686c72e3f8; SESSION=NzA5MzQ4MTMtNjlmOS00OWJkLTlhNmYtNDhiYzliOGIyNTgy
Host: localhost:8080
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

spring log for case 1:

```
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5c3ad125, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@145ce025, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1cecd0a9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2aac60b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3f523dae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@569d6e0d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2a0d8df8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6fa5fc67, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@73b71935, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1deca369, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@12115c28, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1c4a8c93]] (1/1)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.529+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.530+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.533+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Found username 'steeve' in Basic Authorization header
2022-12-04T19:12:51.533+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2022-12-04T19:12:51.533+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.533+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.533+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.expired,u1_0.locked,u1_0.password,u1_0.password_expired,u1_0.role,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_user_id,a1_1.authority_id,a1_1.authority from users_authorities a1_0 join authority a1_1 on a1_1.authority_id=a1_0.authorities_authority_id where a1_0.user_user_id=?
2022-12-04T19:12:51.623+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2022-12-04T19:12:51.623+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.steeve.ui.security.UiUserDetails@43257f5d, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582], Granted Authorities=[com.steeve.ui.user.Authority@1818dc13]]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.623+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2022-12-04T19:12:51.624+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@79b064e8]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.625+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@79b064e8] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@55c423a4
2022-12-04T19:12:51.625+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.steeve.ui.security.UiUserDetails@43257f5d, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582], Granted Authorities=[com.steeve.ui.user.Authority@1818dc13]]
2022-12-04T19:12:51.625+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /user
2022-12-04T19:12:51.626+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

spring logs for case 2:

```
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5c3ad125, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@145ce025, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1cecd0a9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2aac60b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3f523dae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@569d6e0d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2a0d8df8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6fa5fc67, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@73b71935, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1deca369, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@12115c28, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1c4a8c93]] (1/1)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.508+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.514+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Found username 'steeve' in Basic Authorization header
2022-12-04T19:16:05.514+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2022-12-04T19:16:05.514+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.514+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.514+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.expired,u1_0.locked,u1_0.password,u1_0.password_expired,u1_0.role,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.user_user_id,a1_1.authority_id,a1_1.authority from users_authorities a1_0 join authority a1_1 on a1_1.authority_id=a1_0.authorities_authority_id where a1_0.user_user_id=?
2022-12-04T19:16:05.617+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2022-12-04T19:16:05.617+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.steeve.ui.security.UiUserDetails@16584c82, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582], Granted Authorities=[com.steeve.ui.user.Authority@1c4d4500]]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.617+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@41dd4475]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@41dd4475] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@55c423a4
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.steeve.ui.security.UiUserDetails@16584c82, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=70934813-69f9-49bd-9a6f-48bc9b8b2582], Granted Authorities=[com.steeve.ui.user.Authority@1c4d4500]]
2022-12-04T19:16:05.618+01:00 DEBUG 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /user
2022-12-04T19:16:05.619+01:00 TRACE 23352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

tried injecting header `

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

but nothing changes

*edit*

found that the second case session is actually created by the first request that the browser do. these are the request headers:

```
GET /user HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: SESSION=ZjI4ODg5M2ItZWM2ZS00MmY4LTkyZTAtY2MzNmU3OTAzM2Vi; XSRF-TOKEN=b1375a99-f76c-4b01-80b2-32ccdcdc9841
Host: localhost:8080
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

Comment: How do you define the HttpSessionStrategy?

Comment: well, actually i don't define any HttpSessionstrategy...

Comment: In your @ Configuration where you have @EnableJdbcHttpSession, try adding a bean
@ Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {      // maintain session using header (mostly for rest session management)
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }

(In the Spring BasicAuthenticationFilter class, the method onSuccessfulAuthentication does nothing... where the AuthenticationFilter calls SaveRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess)

Comment: i don't have HttpSessionStrategy in classpath... i'm using spring session 3.0, maybe it is deprecated?